# Random start place snake

Tags: javascript

I have been looking into this tutorial:
http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/30/html5-canvas-snake-game

But I am for some reason not able to figure out how to make the snake start a random place each time..

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: omg... Sorry this is off topic, but thank you for posting that link!  I've been trying to find snake since my old Nokia brick.  Still the best phone game to-date, imo...

Comment: @Mike on real computers *that* game is usually called ***Nibbles***

Comment: @scrappedcola, for now I just tried change the numbers of `this.currentPosition = {'x':50, 'y':50};` in order to find out if the place was set there. But without luck.. Even trough I am quite sure that that should be where the star location is choosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where the starting position is being set in the grid:

```
// The current position of the Snake's head, as xy coordinates
this.currentPosition = [50, 50];
```

To start at a random spot:

```
var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * x),  // x = 50 in the default grid
    randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * y);  // y = 50 in the default grid

this.currentPosition = [randX, randY];
```

That's according to the blog, if you copied the actual source, it's using an object instead of an array for the coordinates and calculates things a little different. In the `start` function, you just need to pick a new starting cell.

```
var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) * this.gridSize,  
    randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) * this.gridSize; 

this.currentPosition = {'x': randX, 'y': randY};
```

Comment: I just tried it out by debugging the javascript for the actual game, changing `this.currentPosition` in the `start` function to something like `{x: 200, y:200}` does change the start position.